# Unable to get proper height from internal page used within an iframe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm working in a web project which needs to display another web into an iframe. I read about POSTMESSAGE javascript method in order to tell the page container (the one that has the `<iframe>` tag) the height of the page used within the iframe.

The problem is pretty simple. When I load the "internal page" **on a new tab** (the one that will be loaded in the iframe) and I try to get the height of the document then I get "380" as value, which I think is the correct one being that was not loaded in the iframe.

[image: window.onload() event on internal page]

On the other hand, when I try to render the iframe from the "container page" (the one which has the iframe tag) and I inspect what happens in the same script (that runs in "internal page") and I always get the value of 150px. 
See the following image:

[image]

I don't really know where this value come from, but I couldn't figure out how to get the correct one at the moment you place it in an iframe.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

### Edit

I forgot to mention that I used this approach base on the following URL:
http://michilehr.de/resize-iframe-by-its-content-cross-domain/

Comment: I assume that you have control over both sites since you are using postMessage API, correct?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that. I'm working with both sites... but in production environment both will have different domains, so I need this solution to be cross domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in your post, explaining the mechanism of the postMessage event, almost has it right. Its example code works in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome. But really all you need to do is replace `document.body.scrollHeight` in the iframe source with `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` and then it is cross-browser compatible.

So, as an example, the iframe can say

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>the frame</title>
  <script>
   window.onload = function() {
    // post our message to the parent
    window.parent.postMessage(
     // get height of the content
     document.documentElement.offsetHeight
     // set target domain
     ,"*"
    )
   };
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>See the frame. It is the correct height.</p>
 <body>
</html>
```

and the parent page

```js
// browser compatibility: get method for event 
// addEventListener(FF, Webkit, Opera, IE9+) and attachEvent(IE5-8)
var myEventMethod =
  window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
// create event listener
var myEventListener = window[myEventMethod];
// browser compatibility: attach event uses onmessage
var myEventMessage =
  myEventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
// register callback function on incoming message
myEventListener(myEventMessage, function(e) {
  // we will get a string (better browser support) and validate
  // if it is an int - set the height of the iframe #my-iframe-id
  if (e.data === parseInt(e.data))
    document.getElementById('my-iframe-id').height = e.data + "px";
}, false);
```

```css
iframe {
  border: 2px inset #FF8000;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<iframe id="my-iframe-id" src="http://temp.strictquirks.nl/daframe.html">
  ?</iframe>
```

and this will work in all the modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks friend! I solve it by using IFrame Resizer (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) which actually does almost the same that you propose.

Answer (score 1):

Visually, is the width and height of the iframe what you want? It sounds like your `Window.postMessage` method isn't setting the height. 300x150 px is the default computed size of an iframe in most browsers.

Comment: I think that window.postMessage is not the problem, because it sends values specified in the first parameter, and it does ok. I tested by hardcoding any other value and goes well. However, your answer explains where the "150px" comes from... thanks for that, I upvote you!